Why in German a prepositions makes a direct object, dative?
I have always read that when a sentence has a subject, a direct object and an indirect object, the indirect object is dative but sentences where we tell the position there is no indirect object so why direct objects are considered dative?
For example in the sentence below there is a subject (the picture) and a direct object (the wall) but we treat the wall as dative just because of a preposition (on), so why we are negating the principle (subject (nominative) + direct object (accusative) + indirect object (dative))

The picture is hanging on the wall.
Das Bild hängt an der Wand.


German grammar is not an easy matter but using the terms "direct object" and "indirect object" unnecessarily complicates it even more. Please avoid these terms when talking about German language unless you are a linguist with a clear definition of these terms. Regarding your question, an der Wand is not an object but an adverbial, and der Wand is also not an object. So your question is based on a false assumption.

You have to distinguish between the object of a verb and the complement of a preposition. In your example "Das Bild hängt an der Wand", there is no object at all. The verb "hängen" combines with a prepositional phrase "[an + [der Wand]]", that's all (and the whole thing is a place adverbial). The preposition in turn governs case in German, but that is internal to the prepositional phrase.
Cases appear in a number of different constructions, not just as object of a verb. Case can also appear to signal an adverbial function (with time adverbials in German, not with place), or there can be case agreement (as in "Er nannte ihn einen Helden" (here "einen Helden" agrees in accusative, therefore it is not an object, cf. the passive version "Er wurde ein Held genannt").
So you cannot purely start out from the case form and say "when something has accusative case, then this is a direct object". It only works the other way round: when a verb selects an object, it may assign accusative case to that object (or some other case, depending on the verb and on the kind of object). With prepositions, there is a different set of rules: a particular preposition selects a particular case. – So you have to start out from how the sentence works, not merely from what the words look like.

"Er nannte ihn einen Helden" is a so-called "Gleichsetzungsakkusativ" and, as such, an example of "Rektion" - here by the verb nennen.

No. Government means a case feature comes from the verb, Gleichsetzung (case agreement) means the case feature comes from the other complement. If it were government by the verb, the case would stay the same in passives. Compare: "Er nannte ihn einen Helden - Passive. Er wurde ein Held genannt (predicative complement adapts to the case of the other complement) -- In contrast: "Er lehrte ihn einen neuen Tanz" (two accusatives...)  "Er wurde einen neuen Tanz gelehrt" (when one of them becomes a passive subject, the second object remains in the same case, for it's governed by the verb.

If you search for "direct object" or "indirect object" on German SE you will find ample threads - and in perhaps every one the answer is: there is no "(in-)direct object" in German! This is like using "Dativ" and "Akkusativ" to explain English objects.
In short: to analyse English sentences you have to use English grammar - and to analyse German sentences you have to use German grammar. German has no "direct object" and English has no Dativ.
To explain your example sentence:

Das Bild hängt an der Wand.

The German Dativ is the result of a general indo-european phenomenon: the number of grammatical cases, originally 8 or maybe 9, were reduced continually. German still has 4 cases whereas Latin (one of its predecessors) had 6 and English (one of its closest relatives) has practially given up on cases at all.
Whenever a case was given up other cases had to stand in for it and the German Dativ took over the function of the Lokativ, the case to answer the question "wo?" (where?)*). This is why places in German are expressed by the Dativ while directions are expressed by the Akkusativ:

Wo bist Du? Ich bin in der Stadt.
Wohin gehst Du? Ich gehe in die Stadt.

Compare that to languages like Hungarian or Finnish: they have an abundance of cases (and no prepositions, because with a case ones doesn't need them). They have a case for a place (Lokativ), another for a movement away from something (Ablativ) and again another case for the movement towards something (Allativ). And they don't even stop there! For instance:

talo house  (Nominativ, subject case)


talolta away from the house (Ablativ)
talolle towards the house (Allativ)
talolla at the house (Adessiv)
talossa in the house (Inessiv)
talosta out of the house (Elativ)
taloon into the house (Illativ)


*) This took place actually long before German as a language came into use. E.g. the Gothic language had still 5 cases (the German 4 plus a Vokativ) but used the Dativ in the same way as the German language, as a stand-in for the discontinued Lokativ.

Ok but then how would we explain, "Ich schenke ihm eine Blume"  Wo und Wohin does not apply here.

@khurramShahzad: place/direction are just one, not the only function of Dativ and Akkusativ, See for instance here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77595/why-is-this-not-in-the-dative-case/77597#77597, or, especially, here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77317/aufsetzen-auf-aufbauen-auf-mit-akkusativ-oder-dativ/77344#77344

Sorry, this is full of mistakes. The cases after a preposition don't have meanings. It is not correct that "places are expressed by dative". Location at a place is expressed by a preposition, and a preposition may govern any case. "an" takes dative, "jenseits" takes genitive, "um" takes accusative. In German, the answer to a "wo" question is never a case-marked noun. – For another thing, Latin is not a "predecessor" of German.

If the "cases don't have meanings", then what is a "dativus iudicantis", a "dativus commodi", the "Akkusativus absolutus", etc.? Mir ist heiß (dativus iudicantis) has no preposition (or any other form of Rektion) at all, still it does mean something and the use of the Dativ is not happenstance. As for Latin: to my knowledge Latin was indeed spoken before German and it influenced German a lot. This is what I meant with "predecessor".

I wrote "the cases after a preposition don't have meanings" ! -- If there is an historical explanation for the appearance of a case form, this is something very different from a meaning of the case.

@Alazon: First off, my explanation deals obviously with this "historical explanation". Second, the reason why a certain case comes after a certain preposition can only be understood by examining these historical reasons. As I showed in my Finnish example a language having the fitting case for a certain relationship of a noun simply does neither need nor have such a preposition.

The case that is governed by a preposition doesn't have meaning, for it is the preposition which carries the meaning. If a language has adverbial case, like the Uralic languages, this type of case functions like a preposition: it is an ungoverned case, and adverbials appear in order to mark a particular meaning relation. So adverbial case is just like a preposition introducing an adverbial. The distinction object/adverbial doesnt exist inside a prepositional phrase, there are no ungoverned complements of prepositions, hence no semantic case in such positions.

There is no object in your sentence.
Analysis of your sentence:

Das Bild hängt an der Wand.


das Bild
This is the subject (the verbs most important complement)
The subject is always in nominative case. This subject is a noun phrase that consists of two words:

das
definite article, neuter, singular and of course in the nominative case
Bild
The core noun of the noun phrase. It is a neuter noun, used in its singular form in nominative case.


hängt an der Wand
This is the predicate.
(Note that the term »predicate« is defined differently in German grammar than in English grammar: In English grammar, everything but the subject belongs to the predicate, including all objects. In German grammar, the objects are a separate category, belonging neither to the subject nor to the predicate.)
It consists of two parts:

hängt
This is the verb, i.e. the most important part of the predicate. It matches with the subject in number (singular) and person (3rd person) and it defines the grammatical tense (Präsens which is similar to English present tense).

an der Wand
This is a prepositional phrase. It is an adverbial determination and as such not an object, but part of the predicate.
(Note that prepositional phrases can be objects in other sentences, i.e. something outside of the predicate. But here this prepositional phrase is part of the predicate and therefore not an object.)
This adverbial determination consists of two parts:

an
This is a preposition that introduces a prepositional phrase. It is an alternate preposition, which means, that the rest of the prepositional phrase can be in dative or accusative case. If it is dative case, it defines a place. If it is accusative case, it defines a direction.
der Wand
This is a noun phrase. It is not an object. It is a prepositional attribute (of the preposition »an«). This prepositional attribute is in dative case, so, as part of a prepositional phrase with an alternate preposition, it defines a place.
This noun phrase consists of two parts:

der
definite article, feminine, singular in dative case
Wand
The noun that is the core of the noun phrase. It is a feminine noun that is used in its singular form in dative case.








Who ever told you, that German has direct and indirect objects, told you nonsense. German grammar does not distinguish between direct and indirect objects. German has these types of objects:

dative objects

Das Buch gehört dem Mann.


accusative objects

Irene sieht den Mann.


genitive objects

Der Richter waltet seines Amtes.


prepositional objects

Der Fahrer achtet auf den Verkehr.

Prepositional phrases are objects if the preposition is defined by the verb, like here. (»Der Fahrer achtet über den Verkehr« would be wrong.) In your sentence of the hanging picture, the preposition is not defined by the verb (»Das Bild hängt über dem Tisch« would be correct), and therefore the prepositional phrase is not an object in your sentence but part of the predicate.


And there is also something called »Gleichsetzungsnominativ« that technically isn't an object (because it is part of the predicate), but is constructed as if it was a nominative object:

Prof. Weingartner ist der neue Mathe-Lehrer.

Which kind of object is needed is defined by the verb:

gehören: Dativobjekt
sehen: Akkusativobjekt
walten: Genitivobjekt
achten: Präpositionalobjekt
(sein: Gleichsetzungsnominativ)

In German you need to learn for each verb, which type of object it needs. Some verbs even need two objects:

lehren
needs two accusative objects

Der Lehrer lehrt den Schülern das Klavierspielen.


geben
needs a dative and an accusative object

Der Clown gibt dem Kind einen Luftballon.


überführen1
needs an accusative and a genitive object

Der Ermittler überführt den Direktor des Betrugs.


halten1
needs an accusative and a prepositional object

Christine hielt den Gärtner für den Mörder.



1These verbs also have other meanings that need other kinds of objects. (»Der Händler überführt alle Neuwagen selbst.« »Ludwig hält eine Rede.«)
German grammar textbooks talk in none of these cases about direct and indirect objects. Please forget these categories, they are misleading in German grammar. And please tell your teacher to stop using categories that do not exist in German grammar.
